# Python - Error in my program

Tags: python, python-3.4

So I'm writing a python program that either sets the alarm off or doesn't, but can't seem to find my mistake for R1.

```
T = float(input("What is the temperature in F?"))

from math import *

e=2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369995

R1 = ((33192)*e)**3583((1/T)-(1/40))

P1 = ((156300/R1) + 156,300)

P2 = ((156300/312600))

if P1 < P2:

    #print("The alarm will be sound")

else:

    #print("The alarm will not be sound")


 R1 = ((33192)*e)**3583((1/T)-(1/40))
```

> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python interprets parens next to an object as "try to call this object". If you want to multiply two things together, you need to explicitly tell python to multiply.

So it should be:

`R1 = ((33192)*e)**3583*((1/T)-(1/40))`

(added asterisk between `3583` and `((1/T)-(1/40))`)

Edit: Right, that number is too large for `float`

Using [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) to deal with that:

```
import decimal
#remove import math, that doesn't seem to be used anywhere?

e = decimal.Decimal('2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369995')

T = decimal.Decimal(input("Temperature(F): "))

R1 = (33192*e)**3583*((1/T)-(1/decimal.Decimal(40)))

P1 = (156300/R1) + decimal.Decimal(156300) #removed comma here. That comma was making P1 a tuple

P2 = decimal.Decimal(156300)/decimal.Decimal(312600) #removed excess parens and coerced everything to decimal.Decimal

if P1 < P2:
    #print("The alarm will be sound")
else:
    #print("The alarm will not be sound")
```

Comment: Now my program is saying NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined. @NightShadeQueen

Comment: Hum. Which version of python are you using? `python3` does not have `raw_input`, but `python2.7` should have it....

Comment: Oh shoot, I'm actually using python 3.4.3 Ops @NightShadeQueen

Comment: Oh, okay. Yeah, then `input` is the correct thing to use.

Comment: Another question:  if P1 < P2:
TypeError: unorderable types: tuple() < float() @NightShadeQueen

Comment: Remove the comma from `156,300`. Right now, `P1` is a tuple with first element `(156300/R1) + 156` and second element `300`